# iOS UI: How to make the control that is used in alarm app?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create several controls just like the ones below the date time picker in the alarm app. They look like label controls, but they have a title on the left, the currently selected data value on the right, and an arrow all the way to the right. The Snooze control does not have an arrow, but I believe it is the same control. What type of control would I use to do this?

Any samples out there for this in Swift?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are talking about different styles of cells of a table view.

The first control you mentioned (label on left, selected data value on right) is simply a table view cell with the RightDetail style and Disclosure Indicator accessory view.

The control with the switch is not a default cell style so you will have to make your own custom Table View cell. There are plenty of tutorials online that show how to make your own style of Table View cells. The item on the right is just a regular Switch.

Comment: But doesn't a tableview jump up and down and is scrollable? The ones in the alarm app, are neither.

Comment: You can disable a Table View's scrolling